# Kivy Calling function in another class

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and so I'm here. I'm trying to call a function within a python class via the screen manager, but I don't know if this is the best way to go about it anymore.

Here is my code for a minimally producible example:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


Builder.load_file('TestKV.kv')
class Welcome(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Welcome, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def MoveOn(self):
        self.manager.screens[1].TestCallback()

class TestTabs(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestTabs, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        pass

    def TestCallback():
        print("Success")

class TestScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(TestTabs())
        pass

class ExampleApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.sm.add_widget(Welcome(name="Welcome"))
        self.sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name="Stack"))

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepOrange"
        return self.sm


ExampleApp().run()
```

And my Kivy File:

```
<Welcome>
    Screen:
        MDCard:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 300, 400
            pos_hint:{"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            elevation: 10
            padding:25
            spacing: 25
            orientation: "vertical"

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text:"Go To Next Screen"
                on_press: root.MoveOn()


<Test1@TabbedPanelItem>
    BoxLayout:
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: False  # Important for MD compliance
            do_scroll_y:True
            size_hint_x: 0.35
            MDList:
                id:tasks
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 300, 400
                pos_hint:{"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                padding:25
                spacing: 25

        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x:False
            do_scroll_y:True
            pos_hint:{"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            width : 400
            padding:25
            spacing:25
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y : None
                height: self.minimum_height
                elevation: 10
                padding: (0, 50, 0,0)
                spacing: 50
                orientation:'vertical'
                Label:
                    text:'Basic Information'
                    font_size:18
                MDTextField:
                    id:basic
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 200
                    height: 100
                    font_size: 18
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    multiline:False
                    max_text_length: 15

<TestTabs>:

    id:testTabs
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    Test1:
        id:test1
```

I'm trying to on the button press on one screen, call the function on another screen's child (a child of the tabbed panel).

Please help as I don't know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `TestCallback()` method is a method of your `TestTabs` class, so you need a reference to the `TestTabs` instance in order to call its `TestCallback()` method.

One way to do that is to just save a reference to the `TestTabs` instance when it is created:

```
class TestScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.testTabs = TestTabs()  # save a reference to the TestTabs instance
        self.add_widget(self.testTabs)
```

Then, use that reference to call the `TestCallback()` method:

```
def MoveOn(self):
    # self.manager.screens[1].testTabs.TestCallback()
    self.manager.get_screen('Stack').testTabs.TestCallback()
```

Using the `get_screen()` method is less fragile than using an index into the list of `Screens`. Also, a `self` argument is needed for the `TestCallback()` method:

```
def TestCallback(self):
    print("Success")
```

unless you define the `TestCallback()` as a `static` method (no `self` argument).

Comment: What if I was to put the TestCallback function onto the Test1 class?

Comment: That just makes accessing the function a bit more complicated.